# Django flaky url (randomly omits WSGIScriptAlias)

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

My Django site is producing URLs that intermittently omit my WSGIScriptAlias. If I simply print out `{% url 'index' %}` in my index.html (see my `urls.py` settings below) I randomly (around 50% of the time) get either:

```
MySiteAlias/MySite
```

which is correct, or

```
MySite/
```

which is incorrect.

myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^MySite/', include('mysite.urls')),
]
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and views.index basically does `return render(request, 'mysite/index.html)`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine you might have two urls with the same name, this is where namespaces will help. If you provide a namespace for your `mysite.urls` then there is no confusion on where you should go to

```
url(r'^MySite/', include('mysite.urls', namespace='mysite')),
```

```
{% url 'mysite:index' %}
```